# realize user redirection by entered link with php

Tags: php, redirect

How can i realize this:

When user goes to

```
mysite.com/index.php?g=123
```

He will be redirected to mysite.com/123.

And same for any another entred value. For example: mysite.com/?g=456 > mysite/456; mysite.com/?g=789 > mysite/789; etc.
I have tried, but I know that this way is wrong:

```
<?php
$g = checkValues($_REQUEST['g']);    
if($g)    
{       
header("Location: index.php/$g");    
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `location: index.php/###` but you ask for `mysite.com/###`

Comment: Can you show us your `checkValues` function ? please

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$g = checkValues($_REQUEST['g']);
```

By this

```
$g = checkValues($_GET['g']);
```

Comment: $_REQUEST includes $_GET

Comment: Yes ! :D it also includes $_POST and $_COOKIE. I think we need to focus on the `checkValues` function.

Answer (score 0):

didn't test this but it should do trick 
put this code in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} g=(\d+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ mysite.com/index.php/%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```